# Jest resolves module paths in different order than Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, jestjs, node-modules

In my Node.js project, I have a `passport` package installed and also my own `config/passport.js` file with configuration of Passport strategies along with app config in `config/config.js`.

I set up my `NODE_PATH` to `app:config` (I am on Ubuntu 16.04) so when I run my app with Node, I can just do `require('passport')` to require Passport.js package and also `require('config')` to require my app's config.

So far so good, but when I run tests with Jest and set my `modulePaths` to `app` and `config`, the `require('passport')` call resolves to `config/passport.js` which (as you can imagine) crashes the app.

Why does Jest look into `modulePaths` before `node_modules` when requiring packages? And how could this be solved? I tried adding `node_modules` to Jest's `modulePaths`, but it caused more troubles than solved.
I tried looking into Jest's code but with no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Jest was just loading modules in order I described in question.

For anyone solving the similar problem - this should be no longer issue in the future as I created an issue and PR which was approved and merged to Jest's master.

https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5377

It is now part of Jest - version 22.2.0 and newer.